# Is there a way for Regex to detect a URL that isn't part of an image?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small chatroom that allows users to format their messages with basic HTML. Links are automatically formatted into clickable links with this function:

```
function convertToLink(value) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  var text1 = value.replace(exp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
  var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  return text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
}
```

However, if someone posts an image, the image does not display correctly because the URL is formatted into a clickable link within the `src` attribute (this is what is returned from the function when `value` is `https://www.example.com/example.png`):

```html
<img src="<a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/example.png">https://www.example.com/example.png"</a>">
```

What I want it to do is return:

```html
<!--Input-->
https://www.google.com <img src="https://www.example.com/example.png">

<!--Output-->
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a> <img src="https://www.example.com/example.png">
```

I've tried using `.*\".*` to not format the link when it's part of an attribute, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: @JeffC Those are just example links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a brittle solution, as finding urls in html attributes can be error prone.  But if the url is always between double quotes, you can match that to avoid it. Then use an alternation `|` and capture a url in a group, and use that group in the replacement.

You can make the pattern more specific if you want. Another option might be using a dom parser, and select the elements where this url can occur.

If you want to account for single quotes as well, you can use another alternation.

```
"(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s"]+"|((?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGr6jr/1)

```js
const regex = /"(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s"]+"|((?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
const str = `https://www.google.com <img src="https://www.example.com/example.png">`;
const res = str.replaceAll(regex, (m, g1) => g1 ? `<a target="_blank" href="${g1}">${g1}</a>` : m);
console.log(res);
```